# Finding within a SQL dataset the most recent period in which a hotel had at least one person staying

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursive-query

I have data which includes an ID for a hotel, the check-in date and the check-out date. I am trying to find the most recent period of time for each hotel where there was at least one person staying in the hotel for each night in the period.

Shown below is an example dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE Occupancy
(
   HotelID    INT,
   PersonID   INT,
   CheckIn  DATE,
   CheckOut DATE
)

INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (1, 1, '20/Jan/2015','22/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (1, 2, '13/Jan/2015','20/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (1, 3, '20/Jan/2015','22/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (1, 4, '12/Jan/2015','13/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (1, 5, '01/Jan/2015','10/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (1, 6, '01/Jan/2015','04/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (2, 7, '10/Jan/2015','20/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (2, 8, '11/Jan/2015','12/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (2, 9, '12/Jan/2015','13/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (2, 10, '12/Jan/2015','13/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (2, 11, '01/Jan/2015','02/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (3, 12, '02/Jan/2015','03/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (3, 13, '04/Jan/2015','05/Jan/2015')
INSERT INTO Occupancy (HotelID, PersonID, CheckIn, CheckOut) VALUES (3, 14, '05/Jan/2015','06/Jan/2015')
```

I am trying to create a view and the results I am expecting from this are as follows:

```
HotelID     From            To
1           12/Jan/2015     22/Jan/2015
2           10/Jan/2015     20/Jan/2015
3           04/Jan/2015     06/Jan/2015
```

I suspect you need to do a recursive query but I am not sure how. I should add I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I can't understand expected results. You have 6 rows for hotel 1. Can you explain how do you get 12/Jan/2015     20/Jan/2015?

(1, 1, '20/Jan/2015','22/Jan/2015') Doesn't this mean that you have at least 1 person and this period is more recent then 12/Jan/2015     20/Jan/2015?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. It was a typo. Now corrected. It should have been 12/Jan/2015 - 22/Jan/2015.

Comment: why the answer is 12/Jan/2015     22/Jan/2015 but not a '20/Jan/2015','22/Jan/2015'?

Comment: Because there is at least one person in the hotel from the 12th to the 22nd. Person 4 checks in on the 12th and checks out on the 13th. Person 2 checks in on the 13th and out on the 20th and Person 1 checks in on the 20th and out on the 22nd. Hence from the 12th to the 22nd there is always at least one person staying at the hotel.

Comment: Ok now I understand. `overnight` change this to `at least one person staying in the hotel for each night in period` or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, although it feels quite convoluted. I suspect there may be a better way. Here it is:

```
WITH OverlappingOccupancy
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY HotelID ORDER BY CheckOut DESC, CheckIN ASC) AS RowNumber,
                        HotelID,
                        CheckIN,
                        CheckOut
                 FROM   Occupancy) AS RankedOccupancy
         WHERE  RowNumber = 1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY Occupancy.HotelID ORDER BY Occupancy.CheckIN ASC) AS RowNumber,
                        Occupancy.HotelID,
                        Occupancy.CheckIN,
                        Occupancy.CheckOut
                 FROM   Occupancy
                        INNER JOIN OverlappingOccupancy ON OverlappingOccupancy.HotelID = Occupancy.HotelID
                 WHERE  Occupancy.CheckOut >= OverlappingOccupancy.CheckIn
                        AND Occupancy.CheckIn < OverlappingOccupancy.CheckIn) AS RankedOccupancy
         WHERE  RowNumber = 1)
SELECT HotelID,
       Min(CheckIn) AS FromCheckIn,
       Max(CheckOut) AS ToCheckOut
FROM   OverlappingOccupancy
GROUP  BY HotelID
```